# Python 3: Copying the most recent file in a large directory

Tags: python, python-3.x

So as the title presents, I'm attempting to determine and copy the most recent file in a large directory. Most solutions I have found either list the directory first or use `glob.glob`, and then use `max(file, key=os.path.getmtime)` to determine the latest file.

My problem with this is that the directory I am attempting to search has over 10,000 files, and listing all of those takes forever.

Is there a way that I can "call off" the listing, so to speak, once I've determined what the first(most recent) file is? Or perhaps another method I'm unaware of?

Comment: "Most solutions I have found either list the directory first". What does "list" mean here? Are you saying that the solution will print out every file name? If so, why not just delete whatever statements are doing the printing? Or are you saying that the solution is iterating through every file (albeit silently)? If so, it's surprising to me that it's taking "forever", since iterating through a list with 10k elements without printing anything should take a fraction of a second.

Comment: Instead of building an entire list of 10000 files, you could use a lazy operation like a generator perhaps. https://wiki.python.org/moin/Generators

Comment: You may well have a solution within the OS itself, rather than the Python packages.  For instance, Linux has `ls -t`, which will list files by time, newest first.

Comment: using os.stat(filename).st_ctime should work fine - even for 10000 files (unless you have some slow fs mounted via network)

Comment: The performance will be highly system-dependent. GNU Coreutils's `ls` does not exploit any underlying FS feature to make sorting by file property faster, if there is any such feature at all. It simply uses a sorting function `mpsort` that is not particularly eager in evaluating the comparison function. In addition, parsing the output of `ls` is difficult and unreliable. In the absence of alternative, just wrap `stat` in a generator walker and `max` it.

Comment: finding the maximum value of any list of data will at least take O(n) time so you must visit each entry at least once. The question then becomes what `os` function operates with the least overhead for your purpose. In this case that would be `os.scandir`

Answer (score 2):

You can use `os.walk` to iterate over the directory and apply `max` on the generator.  There are many nuanced depending on your usage case. For example, do you want to walk shallowly or recursively into sub-directories? As a proof of concept, you can trying something like this but possibly modify it to suit your need.

```
import os
import os.path


def mtime_gen(root, *args, **kwargs):
    for dirpath, dirnames, filenames in os.walk(root, *args, **kwargs):
        # NOTE:
        # Here, if you want to skip the depth-walk into sub-directories,
        # you can ignore the `dirnames`
        for basename in filenames:
            path = os.path.join(dirpath, basename)
            # Further heuristics, if any, may help you skipping impossible
            # candidates of the most recent file with the `continue` statement
            # so that expensive `stat` calls can be omitted.
            yield os.stat(path).st_mtime, path

recent_timestamp, recent_path = max(mtime_gen("/path/to/root"))
do_something_with(recent_path)    # For example, copying it.
```

This could be somewhat faster than `glob` because `walk` doesn't do pattern matching. Compared with `listdir` it doesn't populate the list with subdirectories, if that's a concern.

The bottleneck is likely the slow system call `stat`, so some heuristics may help you skip impossible paths and not `stat`ing them, if you already know something about likely outcomes.

Notice that this is just a proof of concept. As is with systems programming in general, you must deal with complications and exceptions carefully. This is a highly non-trivial task.

Comment: `os.scandir` should be the fastest way to go.. [source](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0471/)